# Two proportions, many locations & 3 way proportions?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, biostatistics

I have results and I'm not sure how to test for significance. I am a new student with not a lot of stats experience, so please be kind.

I have whale that makes two calls - X and Y. I measured the prorpotion of each call heard at two locations: A and B. I also measured the proportion of calls in each season at each location (W, SP, SU, F).

So my data looks like this...

A - X  = 30

A - Y = 70
...etc.
and

A -X - W = 45
A - Y - W = 55
....etc.

What is/are the test(s) of significance I can do on this type of data? A z-proportion test? a chi-square test?

Comment: Do you have information about the _number_ of calls observed in each situation? There's a lot more confidence in an estimated 50% proportion when it's based on 1000 cases rather than 10 cases.

Comment: The number of calls is variable in each location and by season. But the total is 5000 of Call type A and 3000 of call type B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to deal with data that have two mutually exclusive outcome values at any one observation (call X and call Y in your case) is a binomial regression, typically a logistic regression. This [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/) has links to ways to do this with 5 different software systems.

You would use location as a (binary) predictor, season as a categorical predictor with 4 levels, and include an interaction term between location and season. The outcome (in R, at least) could be formatted as a 2-column matrix of counts of each type for each location/season combination. That would model the log-odds of one call type versus the other at all combinations of location and season. (Log-odds can be converted to probabilities.) That model allows statistical assessment of the reliability of differences among those 8 scenarios.

With a large data set like yours you might well find "statistically significant" difference among all scenarios. You would apply your knowledge of the subject matter to evaluate the practical significance.

Finally, remember that this doesn't directly model differences in the total number of calls recorded in each scenario, although it does take those differences into account in the analysis.